# Showing $h(z)$ has a zero of order at least 2 at 0

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $f: U \to \mathbb{C}$ is analytic on an open set $U$ containing the closed unit disk $D=\{z \in \mathbb{C}:|z| <1 \}$, and that $f(0)=0$ and $|f(z)| \le 1$ for all $z$ in $D$.

Let $$h(z)= \frac{f(z)+f(-z)}{2}$$
A) Show that $h$ has a zero of order at least $2$ at $0$.

B) Show that $|h(z)| \le |z|^2$ for all $z$ in $D$.

How do I use Rouche's theorem in this example? Thank you.

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with Rouché's theorem. If it is at all possible to use it for that, that would be quite unnatural. Part A) is direct, and for part B), one typically uses the Schwarz lemma.

Comment: I assumed that was the case, but I'm wrong. How do I show $h$ has a zero?

Comment: For $h(0) = 0$, simply inserting is enough. For $h'(0) = 0$, differentiate once.

Comment: for b, I have to use triangle inequality?

Comment: No, I don't see any use for that there. Divide. You want to show $\left\lvert\frac{h(z)}{z^2}\right\rvert \leqslant 1$. What argument gives you that?

Comment: @DanielFischer I was looking at the wrong lemma :-( I'll try this right now.

Comment: @DanielFischer I never got back to this problem but I think I figured it out. I'm not sure about the bounding though: $|h(z)|=\frac{1}{2}|f(z)+f(-z)| \le \frac{1}{2}(1+1)=1$. Also, since $|z|<1$, it follows that $|z|^2<1$. Therefore, $\left |\frac{h(z)}{z^2} \right | \le 1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For part A), inserting $z = 0$ into $h(z) = \frac{1}{2}\left(f(z)+f(-z)\right)$ directly yields $h(0) = \frac{1}{2}(0+0) = 0$, and differentiating produces

$$h'(z) = \frac{1}{2}\left(f'(z) - f'(-z)\right),$$

from which $h'(0) = \frac{1}{2}\left(f'(0) - f'(0)\right) = 0$ follows.

For part B), we can equivalently show that

$$\left\lvert \frac{h(z)}{z^2}\right\rvert \leqslant 1$$

for all $z\in D$. The result of part A) shows that the quotient has a removable singularity in $0$.

> I never got back to this problem but I think I figured it out. I'm not sure about the bounding though: $\lvert h(z)\rvert = \frac{1}{2}\lvert f(z)+f(−z)\rvert \leq \frac{1}{2}(1+1)=1$. Also, since $\lvert z\rvert < 1$, it follows that $\lvert z\rvert^2 < 1$. Therefore, $\left\lvert \frac{h(z)}{z^2}\right\rvert \leq 1$.

The "therefore" is not quite right. And rather than $\lvert z\rvert^2 < 1$ on $D$, we need that $\lvert z^2\rvert \geqslant 1$ on $\partial D$.

Since $f$ is assumed to be holomorphic in a neighbourhood of the closed unit disk, so is $h$. In particular, $h$ is continuous on the closed unit disk, and we have $\lvert h(z)\rvert \leqslant 1$ on $\partial D$. Further, $\lvert z^2\rvert = 1$ on $\partial D$, and hence $\left\lvert \frac{h(z)}{z^2}\right\rvert \leqslant 1$ on $\partial D$. By the maximum modulus principle, $\left\lvert\frac{h(z)}{z^2}\right\rvert \leqslant 1$ on $D$ follows - and unless $h(z) = e^{i\varphi}z^2$ for some $\varphi\in\mathbb{R}$, the inequality is strict.

Without the assumption that $f$ is holomorphic in a neighbourhood of the closed unit disk, or merely continuous on the closed unit disk, the same conclusion holds, it just requires a slightly less direct argument. Since $\lvert h(z)\rvert \leqslant 1$ on $D$, for any fixed $r \in (0,1)$, we know that

$$\sup \left\{ \left\lvert \frac{h(z)}{z^2}\right\rvert : \lvert z\rvert = r\right\} \leqslant \frac{1}{r^2}.$$

By the maximum principle, $\left\lvert \frac{h(z)}{z^2}\right\rvert \leqslant \frac{1}{r^2}$ for $\lvert z\rvert \leqslant r$. Taking the limit $r\to 1$ yields $\left\lvert\frac{h(z)}{z^2}\right\rvert \leqslant 1$ on $D$.